# CacheItemPolicy with HostFileChangeMonitor takes time to clean the cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching

When I use [CacheItemPolicy with HostFileChangeMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and the file changed is taking 5-7 ms for cache to remove the item

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestHostFileChangeMonitor()
{
    var cachedFilePath = @"c:\temp\123.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(cachedFilePath, "1111");
    System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    string fileContents = cache["filecontents"] as string;
    if (fileContents == null)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
        filePaths.Add(cachedFilePath);

        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new
            HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));

        // Fetch the file contents.  
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(cachedFilePath);
        cache.Set("filecontents", fileContents, policy);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(cachedFilePath, "2222");
    int sleepTime = 5;
    Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
    string fileContents2 = cache["filecontents"] as string;
    Assert.AreEqual("2222", File.ReadAllText(cachedFilePath));
    Assert.IsNull(fileContents2);// the test past only if  sleepTime > 5 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to save the time set to the cache in the cache and in the reading check `File.GetLastWriteTime`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestHostFileChangeMonitor1()
{
    var cachedFilePath = @"c:\temp\123.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(cachedFilePath, "1111");
    System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    CashObj cashObj = cache["filecontents"] as CashObj;
    if (cashObj == null || cashObj.addedTime < File.GetLastWriteTime(cachedFilePath))
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
        filePaths.Add(cachedFilePath);

        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new
            HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));

        // Fetch the file contents.  
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(cachedFilePath);
        cache.Set("filecontents", new CashObj(fileContents), policy);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(cachedFilePath, "2222");
    cashObj = cache["filecontents"] as CashObj;
    Assert.AreEqual("2222", File.ReadAllText(cachedFilePath));
    Assert.IsTrue(cashObj == null || cashObj.addedTime < File.GetLastWriteTime(cachedFilePath));

}

public class CashObj
{
    public object data;
    public DateTime addedTime;

    public CashObj(object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.addedTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the item eviction. For example with `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache` you can do this in the next way.

```
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        string key = "key";

        MemoryCache msCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        msCache.Set(key, tcs, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .RegisterPostEvictionCallback(
            (object callbackKey, object callbackValue, EvictionReason reason, object state) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }));

        Task evictionTask = tcs.Task;

        msCache.Remove(key);

        await evictionTask;
```

In the same way you can do it and for `System.Runtime.MemoryCache`, just instead of `RegisterPostEvictionCallback` use `CacheEntryRemovedCallback`